# 'Expected nothing' testing function with doctest

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from collections import Counter

list = [('Hannah', 'Lisbon', 42195, '10-18', 2224),
        ('Eva', 'New York', 42195, '06-13', 2319),
        ('Hannah', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2403),
        ('Eva', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1182),
        ('Hannah', 'Sao Paulo', 21098, '04-12', 1096),
        ('Malia', 'Tokyo', 42195, '02-22', 2449),
        ('Hannah', 'Boston', 42195, '04-20', 2187)]


def participation(data):
    '''
    Tests:

    >>> participation(list)

    '''
    contar = Counter([ elem[0] for elem in data ])

    number = sorted(contar)

    return [ contar[x] for x in number ]
```

And when I try to test it in the Doctest like this it is above:

> > > participation([('Hannah', 'Lisbon', 42195, '10-18', 2224),('Eva', 'New York', 42195, '06-13', 2319)])

In the shell it shows me this error:

```
File "/home/user/Desktop/file", line 38, in __main__.participation

Failed example:
    participation([('Hannah', 'Lisbon', 42195, '10-18', 2224),('Eva', 'New York', 42195, '06-13', 2319)])

Expected nothing
Got:
[1, 1]
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.participation
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Why is this ...?

Comment: Because there's nothing in your doctest? Why did you expect anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Doctests are supposed to contain the expected output following the function call.

So, given your docstring:

```
'''
Tests:

>>> participation(list)

'''
```

The line following the function call `participation(list)` is blank, so that's what the test is expecting to see.  But something **is** returned, and so the test fails.